# Why is it considered bad practice to extend natives on javascript but not ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, mootools

Seems to me, extending native ruby classes would be considered more dangerous.

Comment: Maybe Ruby people are crazy :-)

Comment: I hate gems that monkey patch core classes, unless that is the whole purpose of the gem. Gem developers who monkey patch core classes as part of a more general purpose gem should be launched into space.

Comment: What is a *native*? I have never heard that term before, and I cannot find it in the Ruby Language Specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful about it in Ruby, too. It's just a matter of the prevailing opinion in the language communities; technically there's no reason it's better in Ruby than in JavaScript.

Comment: +1. It's really not that common to extend natives in Ruby - you might see it in something like Rails, but there's a difference between extending primitives in a massive framework and doing it on the fly in your own program.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it has to do mainly with the fact that JavaScript is built into the browser. Browsers already have enough bugs and issues without you making changes to the native objects.  Also, some libraries may have dependencies on core objects that could be affected by your changes.